# How can I add zero value axis in pyqt charts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt6, pyqtchart

I'm trying add zero value axis in chart by using pyqt.

This picture shows graph plotted by pyqt6 charts:

[image: This picture shows graph plotted by pyqt6 charts]

In the above graph, there is no zero value in axis-y.
How can I show zero value?

This is my code for axis-y.

```
self.ob_Chart_Viewer.axis_y.setRange(Config.f_Min, Config.f_Max)
if self.ob_User_Inputs.cb_Axis_Y_Value_Type.currentIndex() + 1 == Config.AxisYValueType.AbsoluteInPercent.value:
        self.ob_Chart_Viewer.axis_y.setTickInterval((Config.f_Max - Config.f_Min) / 10)
        self.ob_Chart_Viewer.axis_y.setTickCount(10)
```

Comment: What version of PyQt6 do you use? What you are pointing out is a bug introduced in Qt6 so it was probably fixed in Qt 6.2.

Comment: I'm using PyQt6-6.1.1

Comment: try upgrade: `python -m pip install --upgrade PyQt6-Charts` `python -m pip install --upgrade PyQt6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I provided a solution using matplotlib NOT pyqt charts; I'll leave my answer in case it provides any helpful information given that after I tried using the pyqtcharts, PyQt5, etc. libraries without any luck even importing them, my alternate solution provides an excellent avenue through which to avoid using deprecated libraries that, for me, immediately crashed my sessions.

You didn't provide any code so I'll give an example solution:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.transforms as transforms
y = np.linspace(-10, 10, num = 100)
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (15, 10), num = 1, clear = True)
ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.plot(np.arange(0, len(y), 1), y, color = [0, 0.5, 1], lw = 1.5)
trans = transforms.blended_transform_factory(ax.get_yticklabels()[0].get_transform(), ax.transData)
ax.text(0, 0, "{:.2f}".format(0), fontsize = 10, color = [1, 0, 0], transform = trans, ha = 'right', va = 'center')
emptyVectorForZeroLine = np.zeros([len(y), 1], dtype = float)
ax.plot(np.arange(0, len(y), 1), emptyVectorForZeroLine, color = [0, 0, 0], lw = 1)
ax.set_yticks(np.linspace(-9, 9, 10))
plt.show()
```

To add a zero tick label on the y-axis:

```
trans = transforms.blended_transform_factory(ax.get_yticklabels()[0].get_transform(), ax.transData)
ax.text(0, 0, "{:.2f}".format(0), fontsize = 10, color = [1, 0, 0], transform = trans, ha = 'right', va = 'center')
```

To add a horizontal plot line at the value of zero on the y-axis:

```
emptyVectorForZeroLine = np.zeros([len(y), 1], dtype = float)
ax.plot(np.arange(0, len(y), 1), emptyVectorForZeroLine, color = [0, 0, 0], lw = 1)
```

Comment: That graph has been made with pyqtchart, not with matplotlib

Comment: I'm sorry, I re-read the question and realized a few minutes ago. If I find the appropriate solution I'll update my comment.

Comment: neither pyqtchart nor pyqt5 are deprecated